# CLLocationManager with MKMapView avoiding multiple instances

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I have a question regarding how to properly set up my app to deal with multiple views needing location information. I have a two views. One a normal `UIViewController` that has a table view, the other, a `UIViewController` that houses an `MKMapView`. Now, both of these views need location information. As it stands, I have a singleton that implements a `CLLocationManager` to get all the user location information for the app. However, I was thinking about some other possibilities because sending a `NSNotification` every time the location is updated to change the center of my map seems like not the preferred approach as opposed to using the tracking methods in `MKMapView`. So, I am thinking about a couple options.

1. When the `MKMapView` appears, pause the singleton `CLLocationManager` and then, when it disappears start it up again. This way, only one location manager is updating at a time and I could still use the user tracking on the `MKMapView`. However, there will still be two objects that collect location data which seems like bad coding.
2. Use only the singleton `CLLocationManager` and update the center of the map based on that by posting notifications in the app.

As it stands, I am leaning toward option 1. However, I am very interested in what the preferred approach to a `MKMapView` and another view that needs location information in regards to how to update location throughout the app and was hoping someone could fill me in on what the proper approach would be. Thanks

Comment: Just tell MKMapView to track the user's location and let iOS worry about it.  I doubt that having two objects dealing with location updates will have any impact on your memory or CPU usage

Comment: why not use a delegate and assign the delegate accordingly when at `viewWillAppear`? At your singleton, you can stop the `didUpdateLocation` when you noticed that your delegate is set to nil (`viewWillDisappear`). This way you can stop the location update when you switch to a viewcontroller where you do not need the location.